# Having issues with Node.js project setting methods

Tags: node.js, methods, parameters

I'm having trouble figuring out/finding anyhting on how to do this. This is a school project and we're making an TODO list where you can add, delete, update and see all your current todos.

The issue im having is in this code:

```
//*Check if method is post
    if (request.method.toLowerCase() === 'post') {
        //*Check so the searchparam todo exists
        if (url.searchParams.get('todo')) {
            //*Get the submitted todo
            let todo = url.searchParams.get('todo');

            //*Add the todo and send success message
            todoDB.add(todo);
            success(todo);
        } else {
            fail("Parameter 'todo' does not exist or is empty");
        }
    }
```

The if statement checking if the request method is "post" is the problem i'm having, i can't figure out how to set the method to POST. This code chunk is supposed to add an todo to the DB, the todo is provided via a parameter: localhost/todolist?todo=MyTodo. But how do i set the request method to POST so it actually posts?

I've seen that you can use options etc to set method, but this program is supposed to use these methods: POST, GET, PUT, DELETE. And i'm kinda stuck on how to do it now. Any help is appreciated, i'll include all the code under here if it's any help.

```
import http from 'http';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import TodoList from './TodoList.js';

const port = 80;
const host = 'http://localhost';

const todoDB = new TodoList();

//* Add todos for debug purposes
todoDB.add('Eat');
todoDB.add('Sleep');
todoDB.add('Chill');

//*Listener to listen for http requests
const listener = (request, response) => {    

    let url = new URL(request.url, host);

    //*Log information    
    console.log('Url: ', request.url);
    console.log('Path: ', url.pathname);
    console.log('Method: ', request.method);
    console.log('Query params: ', url.searchParams.keys());
    console.log('Header params: ', request.headers);

    let data;

    //*Fail function to send user error messages
    function fail(error) {
        response.writeHead(404, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

        data = {
            status: 'fail',
            error: error,
        };
    }

    //*Success function to send user success message
    function success(responseData) {
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

        data = {
            status: 'success',
            data: responseData,
        };
    }

    //*First check if user is in /todolist path
    if (url.pathname === '/todolist') {
        //*Check if method is post
        if (request.method.toLowerCase() === 'post') {
            //*Check so the searchparam todo exists
            if (url.searchParams.get('todo')) {
                //*Get the submitted todo
                let todo = url.searchParams.get('todo');

                //*Add the todo and send success message
                todoDB.add(todo);
                success(todo);
            } else {
                fail("Parameter 'todo' does not exist or is empty");
            }
        }

        //*Check if method is get
        else if (request.method.toLowerCase() === 'get') {
            //*Check so search param is id exists
            if (url.searchParams.get('id')) {
                //*Get the id from param
                let id = url.searchParams.get('id');

                //*Parse to int and get todo with correct id
                let todo = todoDB.get(parseInt(id));

                //*Send message to user
                success(todo);
            } else {
                //*Since we didn't get an ID, we'll show all todos
                success(todoDB.getAll());
            }
        }
        //*The user entered a method that isn't supported
        else {
            fail('Method ' + request.method + ' is not supported');
        }
    }

    //*User is in wrong path
    else {
        fail('Path ' + url.pathname + ' is not supported');
    }

    response.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    response.end();

    console.log('DB', todoDB.getAll());
};

//*Declare server and listen on the port
const server = http.createServer(listener);
server.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the teacher forgot to mention the part where we should use "Postman" to send API requests to it.